# Can I connect 2 power supplies for 16 meters LED RGB strip?

Tags: power-supply, led, led-strip, rgb, controller

I've bought 2 sets of 10 meter LED RGB strip (7.2w/m) for a room. Then I've cut them to around 8 meters each to get 16 meters. Everything seemed fine but one thing, because it's 2 separate controllers, sometimes color cycling can get out of sync and to fix that, I was thinking:

If I'm going to buy a new 144W controller, can I save a buck by not buying new power supply? Because both of the power supplies are 12V 6A (72W), can combining them make it 144W? I really feel dumb for asking this, but I'm on a tight budget.

Or is there another way of fixing that "out of sync color cycling" problem?

Comment: If these are dumb rgb leds and not smart ones, you can try a rgb led amplifier. https://www.superbrightleds.com/moreinfo/rgb-led-controllers/mrgb-a4-cps-mini-rgb-amplifier-cps/1365/3127/ Basically a small mosfet amplifier with a separate power input. So you can use one controller and multiple power supplies.

Comment: @Passerby They're dumb RGB LEDs, and I'm not entirely sure how this is going to help. I'm looking for unifying two separate strips into single one, controlled by only one controller (and remote), and was wondering if I'm able to merge together two power supplies. Sorry for the really slow reply.

Comment: The amplifier lets you connect two led strips, with each one powered separately. The second led strip is controlled by the first, which is controlled by your controller.

Comment: Yeah, that could work but I might have to rethink my Strip situation and drill a hole into my ceiling. I was hoping maybe I could somehow get around the sudden change in brightness by having power start from the same corner as the other strip without running any wires to the same corner. @Passerby